# How to get font properties in pdf... i'm using .net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext, syncfusion

I just able to get name, style, type of pdf font properties.
Anyway to get Actual font, Actual font type, encoding.

Open pdf with adobe > right click > document properties > fonts
i require to get those information

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it is completely unclear what you mean. The properties of which fonts do you inspect? And what is the difference between "font" and "actual font", "type" and "actual type", ...?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification edit. But it does not make sense to try and determine those "actual" entries because Adobe Reader shows them only in case of non-embedded PDF fonts to show which local font it uses to display glyphs from that PDF font. In particular this information may differ depending on Adobe Reader version, its configuration, and the fonts available locally.

Comment: noted. thanks for your information

Answer (score 0):

At present, we do not have support to get font information like actual font, actual font type, and encoding in the ASP.NET Core platform. We have already logged a feature request for this and we do not have any immediate plan to implement this feature. The status of this feature can be tracked through our Feature Management system,

https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/4507/retrieving-used-fonts-information-from-existing-pdf-document

**Note** : I work for Syncfusion.